# how to get an item "Database column" name

Tags: oracle-apex

Oracle Apex 19.1.0.00.15.
how to get an item "Database column" name for IG or Form region like that exists in Oracle Forms

```
get_item_property('block.item',COLUMN_NAME);
```

Comment: Why do you need such information?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an  existing function to do this, but you can obtain it like this for a form item:

```
select item_source
  into v_column_name
  from apex_application_page_items
 where application_id = :APP_ID
   and item_name = v_item_name;
```

You could wrap that in a function of your own.

There is another APEX view APEX_APPL_PAGE_IG_COLUMNS for IG columns, but I can't see how you would need that as to look up the column name you are going to need to know the column name, right?!